# Django ORM - Add multiple columns and aggregates and filter by total

Tags: python, django, orm

I'm trying to get the add 2 Sum aggregates from related tables and another column in a related table, then filter by that total. I'm not really sure if this is even possible through the ORM. I'm also trying to do this in the Django admin using a custom SimpleListFilter.

Tables:

```
class Table1(models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField()
    t3 = models.ForeignKey('Table3')
    t4s = models.ManyToManyField('Table4', through='Table1x4')

class Table2(models.Model):
    t1 = models.ForeignKey(Table1)
    value = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Table3(models.Model):
    value = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Table1x4(models.Model)
    t1 = models.ForeignKey(Table1)
    t4 = models.ForeignKey(Table4)
    value = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Table4(models.Model):
    value = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I think the query below will get the result I want, but when I tried to use the equivalent in the Django admin using `queryset.raw(...)`, it says it can't connect to the database but I get no actual errors in the logs so I haven't been able to figure out exactly what is going on there yet.

```
SELECT t1.*, t3.value + SUM(t2.value) + SUM(t4.value) as total_value
FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2 ON t.t1_id = t1.id
  JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.t3_id = t3.id
  JOIN table1x4 t1x4 ON t1x4.t1_id = t1.id
  JOIN table4 t4 ON t4.id = t1x4.t4_id
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING total_value = 2;
```